# How to get Azure Stream Analytics output into an Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

How to make Stream Analytics output shown in Azure SQL database, do I have to create a new table? If so, what data name and type should I input, refering to Raspberry Pi Azure IoT Web Simulator
https://azure-samples.github.io/raspberry-pi-web-simulator/

I'm new to Azure iot and Stream Analytics.
Currently I'm using Raspberry Pi Azure IoT Web Simulator as a learning material, I followed Microsoft doc and succeeded making the simulator message shown in the blob of storage account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to make Stream Analytics output shown in Azure SQL database, do I
>   have to create a new table? If so, what data name and type should I
>   input

Yes,you need to create tables in Azure Sql Database so that you could configure that as output.

[image]

You could follow this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-sql-output-perf) to configure the output in Azure Stream Analytics.

Since you already have input data, then just use the output alias in the query sql to parse the data. The input data types need to match the output column data types.

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot, my sql db is receiving messages : 3

Comment: @Chen Glad for you!